# How to run the mysql commands in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: mysql, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to do some SQL operations in jenkins pipeline. In the jenkins pipeline I run the following command

> sh 'mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME -P3306'

it is connected sucessfully. But after that when I execute next command like sh "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbname" it shows

> "**DROP: not found Error is hudson.AbortException: script returned
>   exit code 127**"

. How to execute mysql queries in jenkins pipeline when I connected with the mysql successfully. I am using ubuntu operating system.

Thanks

Comment: It's because it disconnects when the first "sh" completes. Create a single shell script with the entire mysql commands that you want to execute, and then call that from "sh".

Comment: Thanks. Whether I want to include sh 'mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME -P3306' in that shell script file.

Comment: Yes, either create a shell script with all of the mysql commands, or if it's just a one liner, do what @hariK suggested.

Comment: Just Thought this link will be helpful : https://github.com/jciskey/jenkins-pipeline-mysql-database-management/tree/master/vars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because command 1 and 2 are running on different shells. Try,

```
sh "mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME -P3306 -e \'DROP <cmd>\'  <database>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I want to execute multiple queries in single sh whether we can do like this. sh "mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME -P3306 -e \'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbname -e \'  \'use dbanme -e \'  "

Comment: I don't think -e will support multiple queries. It's for a single query. If you're going to execute multiple queries either use a shell script or mysql < query.sql.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to write a shell script file how I can load a sql file in that and run in the shell script file?

Comment: Or else how to execute multiple sql queries in single sh line?

Answer (score 1):

Example shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME -P3306 <<EOF
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbname
...
...
EOF
```

Comment: I completed the shell script file but jenkins shows permission denied. It shows "./shell.sh: Permission denied"

Comment: Do a "chmod 755" on the script, that will give Jenkins execute permission. Make sure that the OS user that Jenkins is running as has access to the directory that the script is in, and fully qualify the call to the script, such as "/some/directory/path/shell.sh"

Comment: In my shell script file I wrote like this \n mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME -P3306 <<EOF
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `dbname`
CREATE DATABASE `dbname`
USE `dbname`

EOF \n But jenkins shows MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE 
USE' at line 2

Comment: Make sure that your shell script works outside of Jenkins first, running as the same user that Jenkins is running as.